# A peal of bells - part of speech?

Tags: nouns

I’ve been thinking about the phrase ‘a peal of bells’. Both peal and bells are nouns, but are acting somewhat differently. In the example sentence ‘I heard a peal of bells.’, ‘peal of bells’ is the object. But really, ‘bells’ is the object, and peal is acting almost as an adjective, lending a descriptive attribute to the bells being heard.

It acts almost similarly to a collective noun, where saying a ‘hoard of school children’ is descriptive beyond just saying ‘a group of schoolchildren’.

Is peal being used in a special way? Does this way have a name? Or am I just totally over-thinking this?

Comment: It's no different to "I bought a hand of bananas" vs "I bought some bananas". Anyway, 'peal' isn't a collective term for a group of bells: it refers to the orchestrated sound they make.

Comment: It's like "sound of laughter" or "roar of a lion"

Comment: I opened a can of cat food.

Comment: *A jug of wine, a book of verse . . . *

Comment: You mean a **horde** of schoolchildren - unless someone had stashed them away! Incidentally, a church bellringer told me recently that [peal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peal) has a specialised meaning to campanologists.

Comment: Yes, you are over-thinking things. It's no different to any other NP whose head noun has an _of_ PP as complement. Compare "I heard the squeal of car tyres / the roar of the engine".

Comment: Comments above miss the collective (subset _set_ rather than mere _fairly arbitrary group_) sense of 'peal':  << **peal** c: a set of bells tuned to the tones of the major scale for change ringing >> [[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peal)]. 'In 1538 the whole peal of bells was re-hung again and the organs repaired.' From the Cambridge English Corpus [[CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/peal)]. But in the above example, 'a peal of bells' is an of-PP–complemented noun as in 'a clap of thunder', as stated.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you, 'of PP as complement' answers my question.

Comment: @KateBunting haha, you are right. A hoard of schoolchildren certainly changes the tenor of the question.